Why I'm always getting 503 after deploying Nestjs to Cpanel
I have build the NestJS project and all folders except node_modules have been compressed into zip and then uploaded to cpanel.
NPM install has also been done in the nodejs app in cpanel. But when I test the NestJS URL it return code 503.
I checked stderr.log and found an error like this
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:818
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module '@nestjs/core'
Require stack:
- /usr/local/lsws/fcgi-bin/lsnode.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:815:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:667:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:887:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',

I'm using node 12.22.9
this is my folder structure
enter image description here
and this is my nodejs app in cpanel
enter image description here
I tried to change node version to 20.9.0 it still return error 503, what am I doing wrong?

First order of business for me would be to address the Node version that CPanel is using there. Nest.JS (assuming you're using a recent version) required Node >=16. Does switching to Node 20+ give the same module resolution error? Is it possible you need to run npm install (or have CPanel run it for you)?

Just to suggest some quick actions.
Try:

Application root: public_html/*/*/dist
Application startup file: main.js
Have you run "Run NPM Install" yet?

Why is cPanel recommending a very old version?
